# How to use a search regex for tags in the Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, tags, search, api

I want to simulate the question search using regex behaviour of Stack Overflow using the Stack Exchange API.

For example, using `c++*` for tags will give questions which have `c++` as prefix in tag such as `c++14`, `c++builder`, etc.

I tried the below API request, but it didn't work.

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=C%2B%2B%2A&site=stackoverflow

Here I encoded the `+(%2B)` and `*(%2A)` using UTF-8 encoding.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [advanced search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search); it has a parameter `q` which accepts most of the syntax of the regular site search.

Since most of the C++ questions are also tagged with [c++], it's easier to show that it works with `q=[c++-*]`, which [the following link shows](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bc%2B%2B-*%5D&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

[image]